# pythonic way to hex dump files

Tags: python, hexdump

my question is simple:

Is there any way to code in a pythonic way that bash command?

```
hexdump -e '2/1 "%02x"' file.dat
```

Obviously, without using os, popen, or any shortcut ;)

EDIT: although I've not explicitly specified, it would be great if the code was functional in Python3.x

Thanks!

Comment: What does `2/1 "%02x"` mean?

Comment: "%02x" prints each byte as a 2 character, 0 prefixed capital hex number.

Comment: And what about `2/1`? The question would be much clearer for those who know Python, but now familiar with hexfump cli.

Comment: Take a look at that : << http://256.com/gray/docs/misc/hexdump_manual_how_to.html >> 

"An interation count which defaults to 1 if not supplied but has to be supplied if you want a byte count. This tells how many times to do the conversion before we print the end string. So if you were decoding 4 things, each of 1 byte, you'd say 4/1. "

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you only care about Python 2.x, [`line.encode('hex')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) will encode a chunk of binary data into hex. So:

```
with open('file.dat', 'rb') as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(32), b''):
        print chunk.encode('hex')
```

<sub>(IIRC, `hexdump` by default prints 32 pairs of hex per line; if not, just change that `32` to `16` or whatever it is…)</sub>

<sub>If the two-argument [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) looks baffling, click the help link; it's not too complicated once you get the idea.</sub>

If you care about Python 3.x, [`encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) only works for codecs that convert Unicode strings to bytes; any codecs that convert the other way around (or any other combination), you have to use [`codecs.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.encode) to do it explicitly:

```
with open('file.dat', 'rb') as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(32), b''):
        print(codecs.encode(chunk, 'hex'))
```

Or it may be better to use [`hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
with open('file.dat', 'rb') as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(32), b''):
        print(binascii.hexlify(chunk))
```

If you want to do something besides print them out, rather than read the whole file into memory, you probably want to make an iterator. You could just put this in a function and change that `print` to a `yield`, and that function returns exactly the iterator you want. Or use a genexpr or `map` call:

```
with open('file.dat', 'rb') as f:
    chunks = iter(lambda: f.read(32), b'')
    hexlines = map(binascii.hexlify, chunks)
```

Comment: None of the answers touch on how to implement the second part, I.e. the -e '2/1 "%02x

Answer (score 16):

The standard library is your friend.  Try [*binascii.hexlify()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify).

Answer (score 5):

Simply [`read()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) the whole file and [`encode('hex')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode). What could be more pythonic?

```
with open('file.dat', 'rb') as f:
    hex_content = f.read().encode('hex')
```

Comment: Except you almost certainly want to open it in `rb` mode so it doesn't translate newlines. Also, this is Python 2-specific; in Python 3, you can't `encode` bytes. Still +1.

Comment: Great approach, it works, but only in python2.

This is the output in Py3.4:
     UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: @peluzza: Do you need Python 3?

Comment: Well, I'm doing my best to code only for 3.X, but the gaps are so deep, not only working with hex dumps ;)

Comment: @peluzza: See Raymond Hettinger's answer, or mine if you need more details.